# Jsp include, forwarding request parameter

Tags: jsp, servlets, request, parameter-passing

In my jsp file I am pulling data from the request via `request.getAttribute()`.

Inside this jsp I need to include another jsp.  Will this inluded jsp have access to the request, or do I need to somehow forward on the data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It will be available:

- if you are doing a static include (`<%@ include file=".." %>`) then the body of the included file is  placed into the `doGet(..)` method of the generated servlet (each JSP is converted to a servlet), so logically, the original `request` object is accessible there.
- if you are doing a dynamic include (`<jsp:include>`), `RequestDispatcher.include(..)` is used (behind the scene). As you can see, it requires a `ServletRequest` parameter, which would mean that the original request is passed there.

Finally, avoid using Java code in JSP files. Use EL and JSTL. So instead of `request.getAttribute("x")` this would be `${x}`.